# Aptana Studio 3 loses all connection in Connection Manager after unexpected restart

Tags: aptana3

I have been having some issues with Aptana Studio 3 lately. This exact issue has happened 3 times so far over the last few months and I would really appreciate anyone's help in relation to it.

I use Aptana for both local development and external server development (editing files directly on the server). Some projects have an FTP connection which I upload the edited files to.

Sometimes when my computer restarts unexpectedly (freezes, hangs then shuts down) once it boots up again and I re open aptana all my connections on Connection Manager have gone and all connection for my local projects have also gone.

Can anyone think why this would be the case?